# How are these questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

1. [How is Comparative Advantage a superset of Absolute Advantage?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4476/how-is-comparative-advantage-a-superset-of-absolute-advantage?lq=1) and
2. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/intuition-either-each-country-has-the-comparative-advantage-or-neither-has-one?lq=1,
are claimed as duplicates of 3. [Intuition behind Comparative Advantange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/4472).

I realise that all three questions concern the underlying concept of 'comparative advantage', but each of the three posts asks about a distinct, disparate question using this concept?

Comment: I agree that (unless you already have a good understanding of comparative advantage) it is probably hard to find the answer to 1. or 2. from the material available at 3. For the time being, the mods will monitor this meta thread to see if any community members want to chime in on the matter. If not, we can look at reopening the questions—perhaps with a little bit of elaboration to clarify why they should not be considered duplicates.

Comment: BTW, thanks for sticking with the community rather than giving up and running off!

Comment: @Ubiquitous Thank you very much for your support! I especially appreciate your positivity, which is exactly inspires me to `stick... with the community` !

Answer (score 4):

Duplicates aren't about whether the questions are identical in every detail.

Duplicates are about whether questions are sufficiently close that a good answer to one, answers the others. And that applies in this case.

And by asking the same question in slightly different forms, as you've done on several occasions now (3 here, 2 on taxes under perfect elasticity), without showing any sign of learning, you will increasingly raise suspicions of [help-vampirism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/164022)

(By the way, if you're going to keep on insisting on "intuitive" answers rather than rigourous ones, you will hold back your own learning. Intuition can seem very comforting, and be very misleading.)